# Why I could connect a vm via two different ip address?

Tags: linux, centos, networking, vmware

This vm is cloned from vmware workstation. This situation occured on both the original vm and cloned vm. The following is my steps, I set the static ip 192.168.6.201, but I could connect it via 192.168.6.102 and 201. However I could not find the ip(102) in interface configuration.

```
$ ssh root@192.168.6.102  
Last login: Wed Dec 14 00:54:22 2016 from 192.168.6.105  
[root@clone1 ~]# ifconfig  
eno16777736: flags=4163 mtu 1500  
inet 192.168.6.201 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.6.255  
ether 00:0c:29:70:45:76 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)  
RX packets 2218 bytes 194035 (189.4 KiB)  
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0  
TX packets 904 bytes 150502 (146.9 KiB)  
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0  

lo: flags=73 mtu 65536  
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0  
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10  
loop txqueuelen 0 (Local Loopback)  
RX packets 49 bytes 7558 (7.3 KiB)  
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 TX packets 49 bytes 7558 (7.3 KiB)  
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0  

virbr0: flags=4099 mtu 1500  
inet 192.168.122.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.122.255 ether    00:00:00:00:00:00 txqueuelen 0 (Ethernet)  
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)  
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0  
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)  
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

Comment: That could be caused by any device on your LAN that is NATing the connection to 192.168.6.201.  Running `arp` from your client should at least show you the device's MAC address which you can then look for.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `ifconfig` only shows one IP address.

`ip addr show` should show you all of them

Comment: Finally I find the reason is error comments in '/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-eno.....'. So funny.